# How to use a simple onscroll listener on a recyclerview that is inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

Ive been looking all over the internet and cant find the answer that works for me.

I am trying to create a fragment with an infinite scroller (just like on social network apps like twitter, facebook, instagram, tumblr etc ) and research suggests that a recycler view is the best way. This image show you how i have done it. File -> new -> Fragment -> Fragment (List) [image]

If I'm correct, the next step now is to create an on scroll listener so that i know when the user has scrolled to the bottom as that would be when i load more data.

If i have understood things so far, i think its inside the file MyContentRecyclerViewAdapter here [image] that i have to figure out how where to put my next bit of code for the scrollListener

```
` list.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

            if (dy > 0) {

                Toast.makeText(list.context,"Scrolling up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                // Scrolling up
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(list.context,"Scrolling down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                // Scrolling down
            }
        }

    })`
```

---

Replying to Lalit Fauazdar. This is what I've got right now however for some reason this causes my app to crash. list appears to have a null value for some reason even though my `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` has `android:id="@+id/list"`.

[image]

Comment: The `onScrollListener()` will come inside `onCreateView()` of your Fragment. You can't place it in your adapter class. Also, [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/keddit-part-7-infinite-scroll-higher-order-functions-lambdas-3a11fbd5090e) is a decent article which can help, I was reading it just today and I feel it's worth reading,

Comment: Could you show me the code? I don't think i can use `list` inside of the `onCreateView`. When i've been trying this it would appear as red. This leads me to believe that inside of the `onCreateView()` i cant access the `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` via its `id`

Comment: You don't and can't access the views directly by their IDs even in Kotlin in Fragments. You've to use the rootView for that. See your first line of `onCreateView` where you assign the layout which is generally as `val root = inflater.inflate()` so what you have to do is your have to use `root.yourRecyclerView.addScrollListener()`.

Comment: Share your `onCreateView()` and I'll show you.

Comment: Ive reedited to show my code at the bottom of the answer by the way. Im making this comment because i think thats what makes the website notify you.

Comment: Read my first comment, I told you to put the `onScrollListener()` inside `onCreateView()` of your fragment and not `onCreateViewHolder()` of your adapter class. Put it inside `onCreateView()` of your `ContentFragment`. And posting pictures of code is not encouraged on StackOverFlow, remember this.

Comment: Thanks for helping me by the way, if you post an answer i would accept it. Why isn't posting pictures encouraged on stack overflow?

Comment: Here, read [Why not upload pictures of code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8244632). Tl;dr - We can't copy it to test it or help you for the answer.

Comment: I have another question on how to implement infinite scroll here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846910/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-a-recyclerview-inside-a-fragment if you don't mind helping me on this question too.

Answer (score 0):

For infinite scrolling I would recommend you to use [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) library provided by Google.