# How to implement endless list with a RecyclerView inside a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

How do i load more to my RecyclerView list once the user scrolls near the bottom?

I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26561717/10334519) stack overflow page but I'm still struggling with trying to implement the code from the Kotlin answer into my code.

For better context id like you guys to have a look at [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62645123/10334519), this shows you how i created my fragment in android studio (it was done by clicking on fragment (list) and choosing an empty fragment).

inside of my onCreateView i have this piece of code

```
view.list.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {


            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

                val contentHeight = view.list.height - (view.list.paddingTop + view.list.paddingBottom)

                val distanceToBottom = view.list.computeVerticalScrollRange() - view.list.computeVerticalScrollOffset() - contentHeight

                val metrics = DisplayMetrics()

                activity!!.windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics)
                //val Measuredwidth = metrics.widthPixels
                val Measuredheight = metrics.heightPixels

                // everything looks like its in pixels. It is important that everything is one unit type to ensure accurate calculations
                // Once this is all finished i will ask a question in stack overflow on how to ensure its one unit type


                // using the screen height and timesing it by 2 to know when to load more data
                if (Measuredheight * 2 > distanceToBottom) {

                    Toast.makeText(view.list.context, "Scrolling $distanceToBottom, this is the screen height excluding the nav bar in pixels " + Measuredheight + " more content needs to be loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    // Load more function to be placed here
                }


            }


        })
```

**----------------------Edit---------------------**

Ive been looking into the paging library and I've come across [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHhvbMMXSJ8), however I'm still having trouble putting the code in a fragment. [This is the source code for the tutorial, so this is the code i have used in my project](https://github.com/devplanet-dp/android-paging-library/tree/master/app).

What I think I'm supposed to do is inside of my onCreateView, i have to place this piece of code

```
                adapter = UserAdapter()

                val itemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(view.list.context)
                    .get(UserViewModel::class.java)

                itemViewModel.userPagedList.observe(view.list.context, Observer {
                    adapter.submitList(it)
                })

                list.adapter = adapter
```

However, i am getting errors and some of the code seems to be deprecated. Can somebody please show me the code that i need to use in order to have a RecyclerView inside of a fragment please so that i can accept their answer.

Comment: I would suggest Paging for this. Here, look at this [Kotlin based article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6948-paging-library-for-android-with-kotlin-creating-infinite-lists) to implement infinite list.

Comment: Ive been looking into paging and found a tutorial with some source code however, i cant seem to figure out how to put it inside a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a Library called [`Paging`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) it is part of Android Architecture Component.

Here is the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/#1) and note that the Paging 3 is out https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview

Comment: Paging 3 is in alpha? what does that mean? should i use that version?

Comment: You can use Paging 2 in the mean time if you're not confortable with putting an `alpha` in your application [should I use alpha ?](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/bnw7si/should_i_use_alpha_versions_of_androidx_libraries/)

Comment: Ive been looking into paging and found a tutorial with some source code however, i cant seem to figure out how to put it inside a fragment.